# Implementing operators using data model objects and checking with pyright

Tags: python, pyright

I am working on a class where I have to implement arithmetic operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`), where each operator has multiple overloads, but the overloads are all the same. Instead of copying the overloads to each operator, I thought I would implement it as a data model object, something along the lines of this:

```py
from typing import Callable as Fn, Any, overload
import operator


class Apply:
    """Apply an operator to an object."""

    def __init__(self, op: Fn[[Any, Any], Any], obj: Any) -> None:
        self.op = op
        self.obj = obj

    # Two mock overloads...
    @overload
    def __call__(self, x: int) -> str:  ...
    @overload
    def __call__(self, x: str) -> int:  ...

    def __call__(self, x: int | str) -> str | int:
        ...


class Op:
    """Data model object for an operator."""

    def __init__(self, op: Fn[[Any, Any], Any]) -> None:
        self.op = op

    def __get__(self, obj: Any, _: Any) -> Apply:
        return Apply(self.op, obj)


class Foo:
    __add__ = Op(operator.add)
    __mul__ = Op(operator.mul)


foo = Foo()
a: str = foo.__add__(2)    # works fine
b: int = foo.__mul__("2")  # works fine
_ = foo + 1    # type error
_ = foo * "2"  # type error
```

The idea would be to have all the operator overloads implemented once, with a dispatch to an `operator` for the dynamic behaviour. That way, I avoid multiple copies of the boilerplate code, and I still get all my operators with the overload type annotations.

But the last two lines give me type errors when I check with pyright ([playground](https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoDCAhgDYlEBGJAplEQM5QBiKANFAIIpztgBu1ECTBEAJgCgsOPFDAJBRGLnEqAxuXqMOCBCTgAucVGNQAROe264dFLPkhFuWGBuyKAK2qqYAOnOmVEyhRamAoAH1w1CQYSIAKemoSYF4EfWYUAG1Mrh5ObgBddlyit3d03IBKKABaAD4oADkwFGpDIKDE5J85KABeOyMO4y7gHo9%2BssCTAGIoABUAdxcIMFUAa1kBIRFReh8DoeMAAX5BYTEj4NCI8NVSEnjR9gAPdNQYavqoehgQdKgBx8V1O2wuEiCITCkXuZCeSRSUDePz%2BXwaHwBQOmxiht1hj3CCQRr3eKHwAB8USA0VSoJSMVcgli1BpGAB5NJXfwAEUURCgqxCJDKXnwwCcRFscgUShAfnM2Ou0KiKBi8OSqXSLGyuWKhT1cAKNOarXawx%2BCJ6CEmckVuMiaGosUJzzKFW47HC7rgNMsejNwxAToAriBbH64ETunJeB5KipxOoGIwmGAwAHbmJRJFJhy4tKHLKfFn40FIhBgwTcwh8-ZHHKKyR4ypxS4BqmwHF40R0r8QJNWz5Iln4gAmeMUUn4AaD8uV%2BKmUemePhAdpqAAaigAEZxKuZ%2BuAFRmJfiIA)). It seems to be working with mypy, but I use pylance+pyright for my project and would rather not change type checker.

Is there a way to get this to work with pyright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like pyright just needs a bit of extra help (see [Pyright playground](https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYJw9gtgBA%2BjwFcAuCQFM5QJYQA5hCSgEMA7UsJYpLMUgZwChGd9CokBPXLUgcxL0OLPASJhcaENQLMswDgDoAKgE0ACgFEYAYQASmnQGkAkgDkA4gC5GUO1FCQO3XgNZioO4gBtvxAEbeaIJQAGKkzIwAxn70QgCCuLjenDb2UABEWYnJnCSkUBJSMiAcYPmF-gBWaFFIilkZzOkAJmgKcLxYSHAAFPRo3sAANIW4VmGkANpT9fGknKNzCwC6S4rznGuVVRPLnACUUAC0AHxQZnRoaen2A0OKElAAvGO2t3b3wI-VLzvN9gAxFBlAB3coQMBRADWhQAblJvGBiC16Ip0e87AABepgBEgJEozFQNodGBRHzePpfUYADwmvCQRzOUHoSBAEyg6MUxJxj3xhJaxNJsHJlOpgxGUHprPZzPOjM53IBdhFcApvglQzpDNIRAAPrKQPKjVBDYriellcwYsQ4lAAPLjYmNAAi1GIUEhbW8O1qRGABAqRWkSAIDSyKpJ7VFXR6MH6ktGEgm4Rm%2B3Wm22%2BxWJsupGulrukseuD%2BEijapgfDQ8cT2p2ew2C1GMCbmxNORSNw%2B6BQIAKXc49e%2BEmT1QOxOJ6vFbagQ5tsSEoTAYB7opRLUwrydvRDJUUm8n6TgEAQVJgf13%2B7DIEUZ%2B8k%2BYgfKrxXYF6k-QCJ8MC4kl6F9FDgTc%2BgAJgOL80B-Kl-zQQDV2AmAHz6DIwIySDGG-NBfzghDygAaigABGKCYL-bh4JfKAiLQjDGCAA)):

```py
class Op:
    """Data model object for an operator."""

    def __init__(self, op: Fn[[Any, Any], Any]) -> None:
        self.op = op

    def __get__(self, obj: Any, _: Any) -> Apply:
        return Apply(self.op, obj)
    
    __call__: Apply  # Helper annotation
```

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> reveal_type(foo.__add__(2))    # str
>>> reveal_type(foo.__mul__("2"))  # int
>>> reveal_type(foo + 1)           # str
>>> reveal_type(foo + "2")         # int
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That seems to do the trick.